# silicone roof coating over new torch down roof

Tags: roof, waterproofing

My contractor is recommending applying silicone roof coating over a brand new modified bitumen flat roof that will have a few solar panels.  How common would this be?  We don't technically need the roof coating because the modified bitumen layer has good enough properties to qualify as a cool roof without the coating, but the project manager says that it's a good idea anyway because the silicone provides both better protection against solar heat gain and better waterproofing.  However, I can't find too many people recommending this on a brand new roof install so I'm wondering if this is standard/best practice.  The contractor says that they typically do it for most new torch down roofs, but it seems like it's a more typical solution for an older roof to extend its life.

The contractor is willing to do it for materials cost only, but even that is substantial, and I looked at the price for buckets of this stuff and its clear that the materials price he quoted isn't inflated.  The other issue I'm concerned about is that there were reports that because silicone attracts dirt/dust, without regular pressure washing it will lose effectiveness as a cool roof to the opint where it will be worse than an uncoated roof.  Is the pressure washing actually important or is it more like an optional step to get a little better performance?  The contractor thinks that it will never get too bad because whenever it rains it will wash away most of the dirt.

Comment: After it dries, I can't see it attracting extra dust/dirt than any other roof covering.  It seems odd to do it at material cost without labour added.  Is he paying his workers out of his own pocket?  Maybe his free repair of these roofs make sense to him.

Comment: Applying it will not hurt other than your pocket.

Comment: The problem with any silicone based is the UV will kill it.

Comment: @crip659 we're doing roofing work as part of a much larger scope remodel so they might just be eating the labor costs as overages for the entire project.

Comment: @Ruskes I thought silicone is better against UV?

Comment: No it is not. It will decompose, that why they make UV resistant version, to last longer. Silicone is made from chemical compounds and UV will destroy it.